# Add steps to a model entry in Django

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I am currently learning Django and was asking myself how I could add substeps to an entry.

Lets take a recipe-app for example: A recipe consists of one ore many steps. The user wants to enter a recipe and gets provided with three form fields: Recipe name, ingredients and the option to add many steps.

So how can I implement the functionality to add a ingredient list of unknown length and to add a unknown number of steps?

I only know how to give the functionality of single form entries.

Thanks for your hard work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Model for you recipe called RecipeModel and you can create a second model called StepsModel.
StepsModel should have a models.ForeignKey field.
This way a recipe can have multiple steps and each step is related to on recipe.
you can do the same with ingredients and steps.
its called a many to one relationship you can read about it in documents.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

and you can use JavaScript to modify your forms on client side.

Comment: Ah okay. This is not doable with a single model then and I always need that system you described if i need more than one thing related to another thing then?

Comment: In relational databases your tables cant have rows with different column sizes. so your tables must have limited column size.
to get around that we have to use systems as I described. so we can add it as rows to another table with relation to original table